# Using scopes with create method in Sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

Sequelize [scopes](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/scopes.html) allow users to define reusable queries on the model. You can define a `defaultScope`, as well as named `scopes`. I got these working for `find`, `update`, and `findAll`, but not for [`create`](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/model-instances.html).

From the docs:

> Scopes are applied by calling `.scope` on the model definition, passing
> the name of one or more scopes. `.scope` returns a fully functional
> model instance with all the regular methods: `.findAll`, `.update`,
> `.count`, `.destroy` etc.

**Is it possible to apply a scope to the `create` method, so the returned instance is limited to certain attributes?**

Comment: I am also want to know.

Comment: Did you find the answer @sgarza62?

Comment: @PjotrRaskolnikov not yet!

Answer (score 2):

I also came here looking for an answer to this question, but until there is a more appropriate one, I wanted to share my solution (which is not used in production so far).

Well, I used the `afterCreate` hook rather than the `scope` like this:

```js
afterCreate: (user, opts) => {
  // Prevent from return password after create user
  delete user.dataValues.password;
}
```

I would like to point out right away that this is not a proven solution, but it may be useful as a starting point :)

P.S .: sequelize `6.12.4`

Comment: I think this is better than doing the `delete user.dataValues.password` in the controller or somewhere in between.

Answer (score 0):

actually, ATM there is no approach how to do that.
but you can create new record, than get its id, then do new query with that id and scope applied in order to achieve the same result.

```
const feedback = feedbackModel.create({ params });
const newFeedback = feedbackModel.scope('scopeName').findByPk(feedback.id);
return newFeedback;
```

Comment: Ah yes, I've been doing that, but that requires a second query.